# How to get missed dates in the given range of datetime64 values?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the following DataFrame `df` in Pandas:

```
dti                  id_n
2016-07-27 13:55:00  1
2016-07-29 13:50:07  1
2016-07-29 14:50:08  1
2016-07-30 23:50:01  2
2016-08-01 12:50:00  3
2016-08-02 12:50:00  3
```

The type of `dti` is `datetime64`.
I want to get the new DataFrame `result` with missed dates between the `min` and `max` values of `dti`:

result =

```
2016-07-28
2016-07-31
```

How can I get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) for remove times, then create [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html) and get [`difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html):

```
d = df['dti'].dt.floor('d')
print (d)
0   2016-07-27
1   2016-07-29
2   2016-07-29
3   2016-07-30
4   2016-08-01
5   2016-08-02
Name: dti, dtype: datetime64[ns]

a = pd.date_range(d.min(), d.max(), freq='d')
print (a)
DatetimeIndex(['2016-07-27', '2016-07-28', '2016-07-29', '2016-07-30',
               '2016-07-31', '2016-08-01', '2016-08-02'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')

b = a.difference(d)
print (b)
DatetimeIndex(['2016-07-28', '2016-07-31'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'missing':a.difference(d)})
print (df1)
     missing
0 2016-07-28
1 2016-07-31
```

Another solution is downsample by `mean` and get indices of `NaN`s values:

```
a = df.resample('d', on='dti').mean()
print (a)
            id_n
dti             
2016-07-27   1.0
2016-07-28   NaN
2016-07-29   1.0
2016-07-30   2.0
2016-07-31   NaN
2016-08-01   3.0
2016-08-02   3.0

b = a.index[a['id_n'].isnull()]
print (b)
DatetimeIndex(['2016-07-28', '2016-07-31'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='dti', freq=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution, for comparison. I use `normalize()` to remove times and perform a `set` comparison.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['2016-07-27 13:55:00', 1], ['2016-07-29 13:50:07', 1],
                   ['2016-07-29 14:50:08', 1], ['2016-07-30 23:50:01', 2],
                   ['2016-08-01 12:50:00', 3], ['2016-08-02 12:50:00', 3]],
                  columns=['dti', 'id_n'])

df['dti'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dti'])

full = set(pd.to_datetime(pd.date_range(df['dti'].dt.date.min(), df['dti'].dt.date.max(), normalize=True)))
select = set(df['dti'].dt.normalize())

full - select

# {Timestamp('2016-07-28 00:00:00', freq='D'),
#  Timestamp('2016-07-31 00:00:00', freq='D')}
```